# Why does Will know Morse code?

Tags: plot-explanation, stranger-things

At the end of Stranger Things' second season, we see that

> Will uses Morse code to secretly communicate with Hopper while the monster is possessing him.

**Why does Will know Morse code?** Did I miss something? Hopper and Eleven know it, Hopper due to his military training, Eleven due to being taught, but Will just doesn't seem to have any particular reason to do so.

Comment: At the time, knowing Morse code would have been required to get a ham radio license, something those boys would very likely have had or been working towards in connection with the sweet Heathkit setup at school.

Comment: He might also know it if he was a Boy Scout: https://observer.wunderwood.org/2016/02/22/history-of-morse-code-in-the-bsa/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

We're not given an on-screen explanation.

That said, the 80s is closer to the era when Morse code was somewhat relevant.

As mentioned in comments, knowing Morse code was a requirement for a ham radio license.  We know the are interested in the radio, and AV club in general, so this isn't out of the ordinary.  Some radios also used to include Morse code charts on the front; so Will could have memory from those as well.

Answer (score 0):

It's part of [Suddenly Always Knew That](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/SuddenlyAlwaysKnewThat) trope. Sometime movie/show character just know the skill which can help that. Why and how doesn't really matters here.

But if we really have to guess about Will then remember he is part of nerd/geek group, they are nerdy/geeky kids with certain type pf unusual interests.

And Eleven/Hopper scenes looks like foreshadow of Will using Morse code.